# AWS - Tomcat default page being showed instead of webapp homepage

Tags: tomcat, grails, amazon-web-services, tomcat7

I have a grails web app running on a Tomcat7 server on AWS. Couple of days ago, I run the yum update command, and from that moment, if I access my domain, I can only see the Tomcat homepage!

My webapps folder has a ROOT folder with the grails app, so it should definitely show this webapp's homepage as it was doing until the moment of the update...

Any idea of what configuration may have changed after the update? The ROOT.war on the webapps folder is the same that used to be there, I didn't even change it, so I guess it's gonna be a Tomcat related config. Strange that an update modifies the current behavior of a live system :(. This is an instance I inherited some months ago, so no clue about any specific configuration made before...

Comment: does the exploded ROOT directory look the same? I suspect it replaced your ROOT.war with the stock one. If so, I can help, but I don't want to go down the wrong direction.

Comment: Hi tedder42: you're right, the ROOT folder contains the default Tomcat files, so what I'd need is to redeploy the old war file, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, based on your added comment, I know what's going on here.

### default war on aws-linux (perhaps centos/RH too)

Based on [this question and answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/580392/tomcat-upgrade-replacing-root-war), you can simply `yum remove tomcat7-webapps`. I'm not sure if it'll reinstall on an upgrade, though. Still, yay for package-based management.

### default war on Ubuntu

Unfortunately, upgrading tomcat7 *on ubuntu* causes the default root to get reinstalled. Here are the default_root contents seen in the package: ([tips for using apt-file here](https://askubuntu.com/a/32509/69983))

```
root# apt-file list tomcat7 | grep -i root
tomcat7: /usr/share/tomcat7-root/default_root/META-INF/context.xml
tomcat7: /usr/share/tomcat7-root/default_root/index.html
```

So, the most straightforward way to do this is, yes, to reinstall your war after upgrading.